# How to convert decimal to hexadecimal so that the result is a number and not a string?

Tags: javascript, arduino, hex

I am manually sending numbers to an arduino board as hexadecimal like this: `sendToBoard(0xE)`
I am now trying to get decimal numbers converted into hexadecimal, but I can only get strings

```
const number = 14
number.toString(16) //e  --> string
```

Could I possibly get this 'e' as hexadecimal to send it to the board like `sendToBoard(number) //number === e (in hex)`

Comment: Shouldn't `sendToBoard(14)` or `sendToBoard(anyNumVar)` work? No need to convert--numbers are numbers in JS. Also, 14 is `e` in hex, not `f`.

Comment: `sendToBoard(value)` should be taking a number. How that number is represented when passed is irrelevant. If `value` is 14, you could pass it as `1.4e1` or `0o16` or `14` or `0xe`... `value` would still be 14.

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript numbers are implemented using [double-precision 64-bit binary format](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Numbers_and_dates). So even if you present them in hexadecimal format, under the hood they will be saved using floating-point representation.

if you have a number and you want the `sendToBoard` function to receive a number as its input, then just pass in the number:

```
function sendToBoard(number){
    // you can later convert it to a string:
    const str = '0x' + number.toString(16).toUpperCase();
}
```

Alternatively, if you have a string in a hexadecimal representation, and you want `sendToBoard` to receive a number type, you could do the following:

```
const number = parseInt('0xf', 16);
sendToBoard(number);
```

Hope this helps :)